# List view threshold error in office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I have a SharePoint list containing about 16 people picker columns and I am seeing below error:

"This view cannot be displayed because the number of lookup and workflow status columns it contains exceeds the threshold (12) enforced by the administrator."

Is there a way to change the limit in O365 from 12 to let's say 25? I believe for On-Premises we can but not sure about O365.
IF anyone knows, please let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is nothing you can do about that in SharePoint Online.

You can still have more lookup fields but not in the view.

Have a look at the limits for SharePoint Online in the article below.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sharepoint-online-limits-8f34ff47-b749-408b-abc0-b605e1f6d498